# Placeholder for select menu in laravel 4

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4

I am making a registration form using laravel 4. I am unable to add placeholder to select element of the form.
My code for select is as below.
The class attribute works well but placeholder does'nt.

```
 {{ Form::select('talent', array('one' => 'One', 'others' =>'Others'),null,array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Your Talent'))}}
```

Comment: Check if the placeholder is in the HTML of the page (check the source code in your browser). The Form::select function should just dump the options into the <input> tag.

Comment: Finally i got a solution of how to get this work.
Let the first option of select have the name of your placeholder and keep the value null as below

    {{ Form::select('talent', array(null => 'Your Talent', 'others' =>'Others'),null,array('class'=>'input-block-level'))}}

And in the rules add following code

   'talent'=>'required'

Comment: Your above hack works as a simple solution @user3340945 but the problem still exists if we think about how to do this in a more correct way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML select element has no placeholder attribute (only input does), so even if it's in the HTML for your input, it won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply now i know how to use html select